# "Attempted to lock an already-locked dir" using SVNANT

Tags: java, svn, locked, svnant

I'm using SVNANT for checking out my project directory on my Windows XP machine. The first time I've used tortoiseSVN for the check out.. as result I obtained an error message relative to the incompatible versions so I had to fix it using a downgrade script. Now,I can't use tortoiseSVN for any operation on my project folder because of this uncompatibility issue. The problem is that everytime I try to check out the project with SVNANT I receive this message:

```
Attempted to lock an already-locked dir
```

to be fixed this problem require a

> svn cleanup

but as told above I cannot use Tortoise. How could I fix the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

right click on your project --> Team --> Cleanup, this will remove the empty ".lock" files automatically created by subclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Now change path of cleanup(for macOS)
select project -> Modify -> cleanup